# Javascript test fixture, or, how to get my specs to run on a single-page app

Tags: javascript, testing, single-page-application, functional-testing

Let's pretend I have a SPA and I want to run **functional** specs (e.g. mouse wheel scrolling, touch and drag scrolling, click and hold popup handling, etc) against it from many browsers/devices (using a tool like karma, for instance).

I believe that frameworks like mocha, jasmine, etc support this sort of behavior via [test fixtures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture), but I can't seem to get this to work. In addition, I don't see how I would use karma with mocha/jasmine to launch these tests (see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/488 for discussion of setting the karma context.html page in which tests run, in an iframe).

I know that [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) et al are designed for this type of end-to-end functional testing, but I'm trying to stick to **client-side** javascript (instead of WebDriver ports).

What's an easy way to get JS specs running on a SPA with results reported somewhere (to the console, for instance)?

**EDIT:** I guess that the fixture idea, to me, seems backwards. It supports loading html before a test executes, but I'm thinking that the html page exists first and then the tests are executed on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I've used QUnit (https://qunitjs.com/) for this before and it has worked for me.